# Summarizing a column in Crystal Reports by filtering out custom values from a different column

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I am new to SAP Crystal Reports 2020 and i was wondering how we can summarize(sum) a column by filtering out certain values from a different column.

For example in sql we have:
column 1 = ID, column 2 = type of service, column 3 = duration
And I'm looking to query three columns given below:

ID, (case when column 2 not in ('w','x','y','z') then sum(column 3) end) as customized col 1,
(case when column 2 not in ('x','z') then sum(column 3) end) as customized col 2.

How can we replicate this in Crystal Reports?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to create a formula like:
IF  Then <Value_of_Column A> ELSE 0

Then, total that formula.

Comment: Does it take multiple values within the if condition? For example: If {column 3} in ('x', 'y','z') then sum({column 3}). It's not accepting this. Do you know of another way to write this?

Comment: Yes, but follow the logic in my answer. The SUM() is NOT in the detail level (IF/THEN) formula.  You first create the formula.  Then, is a SEPARATE step, you total the formula.